# Azure Cloud Service deployed but Site Url not resolvable

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud

I have deployed a Azure Cloud Service and Azure says that it is running. However, the Site Url does not resolved. I have waited 24 hours or more to ensure it is not the DNS cache not updating. Any recommendations? I'm simply using the template Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio for ASP.NET and published it through Visutal Studio.

Comment: why are you using Cloud Services? Can't you go with App Service?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Long story short, I'm a cybersecurity consultant not a developer. I need to register a cloud service to exploit a vulnerability in a client's cloud setup.

Comment: probably there's some issue with your web site. Try RDP and run it locally first

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this by simply deleting the Azure Cloud Service and re-creating it again. Azure bug I guess.